# Yii scenario based safe attributes

Tags: php, yii

I have a Product model with the following rules:

```
...
array('normal_price, company_id, purchase_price', 'safe', 'on' => 'adminList'),
array('normal_price, company_id', 'safe', 'on' => 'list'),
...
```

And I call the following function:

```
$product->scenario = 'list';
$product->safeAttributeNames;
```

The code above should only return `['normal_price, company_id']`, but I get the `purchase_price` as well, all time. Even if I delete the first rule for the `adminList` scenario.

I would need the list of attributes, that I specify.
What could be the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out, that I had a length rule for the purchase rule without scenario. When I commented out every other rules, it worked what I wanted.

Description:

To only get the 'safe' attributes, you should not have any other rule for those attributes in that scenario.

My solution was to set the default scenarios to every rule like:

```
array('id', 'require', 'on' => 'insert, update')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$product->setScenario('list');
```